# Why all permutations of i.i.d. samples are equally likely?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ i.i.d

Why is$$P(X_{i_1}<X_{i_2}<\cdots<X_{i_3})=P(X_{j_1}<X_{j_2}<\cdots<X_{j_3})=\frac{1}{n!}$$for all $i,j$?

I think we can reason this by probability measure is translational invariant? (But I don't think this is true in general)

Update: I know the intuition but please give a mathematical proof of this

Answer (score 2):

Since $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is i.i.d., the sequence $(X_{\pi_1,},\ldots,X_{\pi_n})$ is also i.i.d., for any permutation $\pi_1\pi_2\cdots\pi_n$ of the numbers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. In particular, it follows that $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is equal in distribution to $(X_{\pi_1,},\ldots,X_{\pi_n})$. That is, $\mathbb P((X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in A)=\mathbb P((X_{\pi_1},\ldots,X_{\pi_n})\in A)$ for all $A$. By choosing $A$ to be the set of all increasing tuples, it follows that
$$
\mathbb P(X_1<X_2<\cdots <X_n)=\mathbb P(X_{\pi_1}<X_{\pi_2}<\cdots <X_{\pi_n}).
$$
To show that this probability is equal to $1/n!$, one must assume that the random variables are non-atomic, that is, for any deterministic number $a$, we must have that $\mathbb P(X_1=a)=0$. (Otherwise, one must take into account the possibility for there to be multiple variables with the same value.) Once we make this assumption, the fact that the probability is $1/n!$ follows by summing up the probability over all $n!$ permutations: the total probability must be 1, and each probability being summed is the same.

Comment: can you elaborate between $P(X_i\in A)=P(X_{\pi_i}\in A),\forall A$